# How to dynamically create and destroy datepicker in materializecss

Tags: datepicker, materialize

I want to initialize and destroy datepicker in materializecss. I know how to initialize but unable to find it how to destroy.

I have one textbox and one dropdown.based on dropdown, the textbox type is changed. so when user select dob, I initialized textbox with materializecss datepicker but after that I am not able to change textbox back to its normal mode, I mean where user can insert text or number.

I am using below code to initialize -

```
$('#txtDatePicker').pickadate({
                selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
                selectYears: 100 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

A datepicker usually has 3 buttons, however if these buttons are initialized without values ie. *today: ""* they will not be shown.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
   today: '',
   clear: 'Clear selection',
   close: 'Cancel'
});
```

For more information see: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#buttons

Comment: nope that didn't work. The plugins that you are talking about is 'jQuery date & time input picker' and I am talking about materializecss http://materializecss.com/forms.html.

Comment: As far as i know materializecss uses pickdate.js

Comment: ok may be they are using part of the code not at all. btw I tried your suggestion, that didn't work.

Comment: I've now extracted the datepicker out of the [materialize website](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker) and modified it so that you have a button to close it. I uploaded an example to my website: [click here](http://use1ess.bplaced.net/stack/datepicker/)

Comment: I think you understood my question in wrong way. so lets say you have initialized date picker and now I want to destroy it, so that simple text can be written into it.

Comment: Well you could do something similar to [this](https://codepen.io/Cr0up13r/pen/vhnao).

Answer (score 0):

From your comment

> so lets say you have initialized date picker and now I want to destroy it, so that simple text can be written into it.

I think that if you only need a simple text can be written into it. Just add an option like this

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  editable: true
});
```